# Can a validation rule error message resolve to a custom label?

Tags: validation, customlabel

Is there anyway to make the error message of a validation rule resolve to a custom label? The following url indicates that it's not possible, but I just wanted more verification:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000009iptIAA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't. I think you have 2 options, depending on what exactly you want to do

1. You can use the translation workbench to translate the error message (assuming that's what you're trying to accomplish.
2. Handle the validation in a trigger, which then uses the custom label as the error message.